# Remove files from glusterfs cache (hardlinks)

Tags: linux, glusterfs

How to remove files from glusterfs cache (hardlinks) after file deletion directly on brick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go inside gluster 'cache' folder eg. /data/.glusterfs/.glusterfs

Find and copy these files with dir structure to safe place

`find . -links 1 -type f -exec rsync -arvRH --progress --remove-source-files {} /data/old_files/ ;`

Check & remove.